# Embedding a gh-pages link onto another gh-pages link using iframe

Tags: iframe, embed, github-pages, p5.js

I was trying to use the p5.js framework in order to add a simple drawing project (which is hosted on gh-pages) onto a different application (on a index.html page). I want it to appear as a 300x450px window on my page and it should be editable, but have not figured out how to work with this p5.js process.

I am now trying to embed my gh-pages url directly onto my other application page using the  tag, but I haven't been able to do this successfully. It does not show up at all, let alone work. Is there a way to embed this AND also make it so that the user can play with the app while it is embedded on your site?

Any helpful tips are appreciated!

** I am trying to add code similar to below onto my index.html page. The point is to have my github-pages app show up on my index.html in a 300x300 div and also be functional (essentially embedding it onto the page). I don't have another site or project to use as an example now, but have seen it done recently.

`<iframe src="https://linkhere.github.io/my-app/" frameborder="0" 
style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:300px;width:300px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="300px" width="300px">
</iframe>`

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi! I've updated my questions. I can't find an exact example, which is why its been difficult to find an answer. I hope that it's helpful! @KevinWorkman

Comment: Can you link us to the website where you're trying to do this? It's really hard for us to help without being able to run your code.